# How to insert a line break in Horizontal Axis label of a graph in Oracle Analytics Cloud?

Tags: oracle, graph, cloud, analytics

I have a graph created in Oracle Analytics Cloud (OAC). Lets say Graph shows sales by Year,Quarter.
In my group By (X axis), I have dragged Year and Quarter and made orientation angle as 0. But Year and Quarter is shown in a straight line. Is there a way I can show year below Quarter..ie in 2 lines instead of 1?

Tried fiddling with XML configuration, but nothing positive so far. What I want to achieve is below image
What I want is like below

[image]